# How can I fix this error with installing packages using npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-36-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "create-react-app"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /tmp/npm-7054-19e3727d
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/tmp/npm-7054-19e3727d'
npm ERR! rofs This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! rofs and is related to the file system being read-only.
npm ERR! rofs 
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/path[...]/npm-debug.log
```

I have just started learning react and I get this following error when I try to install the `create-react-app`.

I use Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I looked online but the solutions that I found so far were not very helpful. What I have tried already:

```
1. Reinstalling nodejs and npm 
2. Creating .npm-global and and adding the file to the path
3. Tried --no-bin-links
```

Comment: looks like you have a read only folder that you are trying to mutate. probably should `chown` it

Comment: You may want to try adding the [`--no-bin-links`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) argument to the install command. e.g. `$ npm install create-react-app --no-bin-links`, however I'm not sure how reliant `create-react-app` is on having bin links - but worth trying.

Comment: If using docker you can try to pin down the `npm` version as mentioned here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4838#issuecomment-1148412095. Hard to debug without more specific information about the bounty issuer's environment/setup.

Comment: Could you please check your node/npm version? https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html says `Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6`

Comment: what is the location you currently trying to run this command please type `pwd` at terminal at the location you trying to run `npx create-react-app` and add it to the question

Comment: @Mehrshad, to confirm, do you have the _exact_ same npm, node, and Ubuntu versions installed as the original asker of this question? If not, what npm, node, and Ubuntu versions are you running?

Comment: I would recommend you to use NVM to install NodeJS, it's the simplest way to install and i never had any issues using that,
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have installed Node.js through the `apt` package manager.

Unfortunately the version provided for [`bionic (18.04LTS)`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nodejs) is rather old and as per [@Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381031/anton)'s comment `create-react-app` requires Node.js version 14 and up.

So uninstall the version of `nodejs` you acquired from `apt` via `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs`.

Then following the [instructions provided on Node.js's site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions).

Install a more recent version of Node.js from [NodeSource's Ubuntu installation scripts](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall).

I would recommend the latest LTS version which is current version 16.

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Then attempt to reinstall `create-react-app` via `npm install -g create-react-app`.

Comment: Also, `create-react-app` doesn't recommend a global install anymore, `npx create-react-app` is preferred (https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when your hard disk file cannot be read or there is a problem among the files.
Try to test in another drive and hard disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the npm modules directory and run npm install or yarn install again.

If you’re running a fresh machine without nodejs installed, I highly recommend downloading node with NVM manager.

Just google “Install node with nvm” usually Digital Ocean writes good blogs that are really easy to follow